# NoReverseMatch at /hrfinance/home/ Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have no idea why i have error saying "Reverse for 'lscholarship' not found. 'lscholarship' is not a valid view function or pattern name." when i am trying to run http://127.0.0.1:8000/hrfinance/home/. Inside my views.py, i have already defined scholarship instead of lscholarship and i wrote views.scholarship in my urls.py.

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %} Title {% endblock %}</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    {% block link %}
    {% endblock %}
</head>

<body>
{% block body %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
def scholarship(request, id=None):
    query_results = []
    if request.POST.get('delete'):
        Scholarship.objects.filter(id__in=request.POST.getlist('item')).delete()
        return redirect('/hrfinance/lscholarship/')

    elif request.POST.get('add'):
        form = ScholarshipForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            scholarship = form.save(commit=False)
            scholarship.save()
            return redirect('/hrfinance/lscholarship/')
    else:
        form = ScholarshipForm()
    id = request.GET.get('scholarship')
    query_results = Scholarship.objects.all()
    data = {
         'query_results':query_results,
         'form':form
       }
    return render(request, 'hrfinance/add_remove_scholarship.html', data)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^home/$', views.home, name='home'),
    #timesheet to be filled up by students
    url(r'^timesheet/$', views.timesheet, name='timesheet'),
    #list of timesheets under 'View Timesheet'
    url(r'^ltimesheet/$', views.ltimesheet, name='ltimesheet'),
    #list of applications under 'View Application'
    url(r'^lapplication/$', views.lapplication, name='lapplication'),
    #list of scholarships under 'Add/Remove Scholarship'
    url(r'^lscholarship/$', views.scholarship, name='lscholarship'),
    url(r'^base/$', views.base, name='base'),
]
```

below is the traceback:

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/hrfinance/home/
>
> Django Version: 1.11.1 Python Version: 2.7.13 Installed Applications:
>   ['hrfinance.apps.HRFinanceConfig',  'django.contrib.admin', 
>   'django.contrib.auth',  'django.contrib.contenttypes', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions',  'django.contrib.messages', 
>   'django.contrib.staticfiles'] Installed Middleware:
>   ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
>
> Template error: In template D:\curtin\year3 SEM
>   2\XiMing_2Jul\myHDR\hrfinance\templates\hrfinance\base.html, error at
>   line 0    Reverse for 'lscholarship' not found. 'lscholarship' is not
>   a valid view function or pattern name.   1 :     2 :
>       3 :     4 :         5
>   :     {% block title %} Title {% endblock %}    6 :
>   
>   7 :     {% block link %}    8 :     {% endblock %}    9 : 
>   10 :
>
> Traceback:
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py"
>   in inner
>     41.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in
>   _get_response
>     187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in
>   _get_response
>     185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "D:\curtin\year3 SEM 2\XiMing_2Jul\myHDR\hrfinance\views.py" in
>   home
>     11.     return render(request, 'hrfinance/home.html')
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
>     30.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in
>   render_to_string
>     68.     return template.render(context, request)
>
> File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in
>   render
>     66.             return self.template.render(context)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
>     207.                     return self._render(context)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in
>   _render
>     199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
>     990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in
>   render_annotated
>     957.             return self.render(context)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in
>   render
>     177.             return compiled_parent._render(context)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in
>   _render
>     199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
>     990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in
>   render_annotated
>     957.             return self.render(context)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in
>   render
>     72.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
>     990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in
>   render_annotated
>     957.             return self.render(context)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in
>   render
>     458.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py" in reverse
>     91.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix,
>   *args, **kwargs)))
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py" in
>   _reverse_with_prefix
>     497.         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
>
> Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /hrfinance/home/ Exception Value:
>   Reverse for 'lscholarship' not found. 'lscholarship' is not a valid
>   view function or pattern name.

project urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

url(r'^hrfinance/', include('hrfinance.urls', namespace='hrfinance')),]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Please post your base.html also

Comment: @ArpitSvt  I have updated my question to include base.html

Comment: Please post hrfinance/home.html' also

Comment: Also post your project urls.py

Comment: @zaidfazil i have edited my question to include project urls.py

Answer (score 0):

Try `redirect()` method like this in `views`,

```
return redirect('hrfinance:lscholarship')
```

instead of,

```
return redirect('/hrfinance/lscholarship/')
```

assuming your project `urls.py` contains,

```
url(r'^hrfinance/', include('hrfinance.urls', namespace='hrfinance')),
```

**EDIT**

change your urlpattern,

```
url(r'^lscholarship/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.scholarship, name='lscholarship'),
```

Comment: doesn't work and my project urls.py is the same as wat u  wrote

Comment: with this error : Reverse for 'lscholarship' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'hrfinance/lscholarship/(?P<id>\\d+)/$']